# Normal Html styling vs asp.net MVC elements styling

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I spent some time working with normal html elements and javascript, ive recently started working with asp.net mvc and ive realized that a normal html button compared to an asp button with the same styling will look different. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Check the CSS style applied in the .cshtml file. It sais "class=.." and remove that. Buttons will look like default html buttons.

Comment: You have to compare the actually generated html code in both examples. When it's the same, the result/page should look the same also (considering same css in both cases).